# C: nested nested for loop order

Tags: c

this code outputs:

```
i is 1 j is 1 

i is 2 j is 1

i is 2 j is 2
```

among other things but the question I have pertains to the beginning of it.

My question is as you can see in the second output line, `i` is 2, but `j`is still 1. Why are they both not 2?

The bodies of the outer and inner loop had already ran once. Shouldn't j have been incremented as well?

It had printed once already, so it's running a second time shouldn't of it been incremented? I've watched videos but am struggling with this concept.

```
#include <stdio.h>



 int main(void) {

    int i, j;

    for (i=1; i<=5; i++) {

        for (j=1; j<=i; j++) {
            printf("i is %i j is %i",i, j);
            printf("\n"); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For every `i` value inner loop variable `j` start from `1` only`(j=1)`

Comment: Try adding `printf`s before and after the inner loop and you'll understand exactly what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Below is how your for loops executes,

First pass:
initialises i=1 goes to inner for loop

1. initialises j=1 and prints i is 1 j is 1
2. increments j, j is 2 now and it is greater than i so goes back to outer for loop

Second pass:
increments i, i=2 goes to inner for loop

1. initialises j=1 and prints i is 2 j is 1
2. increments j, j=2 and prints i is 2 j is 2
3. increments j, j is 3 now and it is greater than i so goes back to outer for loop

and so on it continues till i is incremented to 6.

You can go through below link to know more about usage of for loop in c

https://beginnersbook.com/2014/01/c-for-loop/

Hope it clears your doubt.

Answer (score 0):

There are two loops here.  An i outer loop and a j inner loop.  And for every i outer loop you run the j inner loop i times incrementing j by 1 for every iteration of the inner loop.  So when i is 2 for example, your j inner loop runs 2 times.  And the j inner loop always starts with j=1 because the loop gets reinitialized for every iteration of the outer loop (since you set j=1);

This is why you see two print lines when i is 2 since the inner loop executed 2 times.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i=1; i<=5; i++) {

    for (j=1; j<=i; j++) {
        printf("i is %i j is %i",i, j);
        printf("\n"); 
    }
}

i = 1
    j = 1
        print msg
    j = 2, j is greater than i, stop inner loop

i = 2
    j = 1
        print msg
    j = 2
        print msg
    j = 3, j is greater than i, stop inner loop

and so on....
```